# Java 8 Streams intermediate operations produce new streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

When I invoke intermediate operations on streams, do they create new stream for each intermediate operation?

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);

list.stream().filter(i -> i > 4).map(o -> o*2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How many streams did it create? 1 or 3?

Comment: (confused by the mix of answer and question) Co-incidentally or on purpose, the number of elements filtered in the input is three as well. So if you could clarify further, if your question is that - *"For each element, there would a new Stream?*" Or is your question such that "*For each operation like `filter`, `map`, there would be a new Stream*?

Comment: Thanks Naman I got my answer.

Comment: oh okay @Naman. I see where you got confused. My question clearly states if every new intermediate operation creates and returns a new stream. That was my question. And answers also reflect that.

Comment: I edited my question. Now filter function returns 1 value. This answer is the most concise. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60677967/4828463. However, I didn't accept it as it lacked deep details.

Comment: If you use Intellij Idea, it can give you a hint on what specific stream is returned on each operation. Check `Inlay hints > Method chains` option.

Comment: I use Eclipse @Eugene and Eclipse > Intellij any day (except in this situation :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, one of the concepts of functional programming is `pure functions` that deterministic and have no-side effect that called `immutability`. All of the intermediate operations in the `Stream` api are immutable and returns new Stream.

As mentioned in the [`Oracle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) document, all of the intermediate operations like `filter`, `map` and etc returns new stream. For example document of `map` method is as follow:

```
Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.
>   This is an intermediate operation.
>
> Type Parameters:
>   R - The element type of the new stream
>   Parameters:
>
> mapper - a non-interfering, stateless function to apply to each element
>
> Returns:
>   **the new stream**

For more information, you can take a look at the Stream implementation in Java (For example `map` method that returns a new `StatelessOp`)

```
public final <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super P_OUT, ? extends R> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    return new StatelessOp<P_OUT, R>(this, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
                                 StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED | StreamOpFlag.NOT_DISTINCT) {
        @Override
        Sink<P_OUT> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<R> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedReference<P_OUT, R>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void accept(P_OUT u) {
                    downstream.accept(mapper.apply(u));
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the call to filter and map both create a new **StatelessOp** which is a new **ReferencePipeline** that implements the **Stream** interface. You are creating 3 new StatelessOp objects.

Answer (score 2):

In a word - yes. Every call to such a method creates another `Stream` object. You could see this if you broke down the chain and assigned these intermediate operations to variables as you go long:

```java
Stream<Integer> s1 = list.stream();
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1));
Stream<Integer> s2 = s1.filter(i -> i > 2);
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2));
Stream<Integer> s3 = s2.map(o -> o*2);
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s3));
List<Integer> result = s3.collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

Sample output:

> 1163157884
>   1747585824
>   1149319664
>   [6, 8, 10]

Comment: Thanks Mereinik. Can you also please answer my side question?

Comment: If multiple threads are trying to insert a value into a non-synchronized List, would the end List have a discrepancy? Mind you that multiple threads are inserting values simultaneously however at the time of reading, they all come back to main method. List is read when all insertions are complete.

Comment: @Faraz if you have another unrelated question, please post it as a question, not as a comment

Comment: Would it be possible for you to answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60678142/4828463

Comment: @Faraz sorry, I have no experience with Apache Spark

Comment: Thank @Mureinik. I found a similar question (List .add thread-safety) for C#. I believe same thing would apply to Java.

Comment: Confused by the other answers, [not really sure what the question was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677932/java-8-streams-intermediate-operations-produce-new-streams#comment107361170_60677932)! Possible to edit?