# Spark Accumulator Thread Safety and .value() performance

Tags: apache-spark

Accumulators are not thread-safe by design. However, when `.value()` is called, documentation says that values come back to the main driver thread. Does driver program gets the up to date values?

Moreover, is `.value()` operation expensive since it forces all the worker threads to respond and send back values to main driver program? If so, then what are the alternatives?

I have my custom thread safe Accumulator. However, I feel like it might be an overkill.

Answer (score -1):

> Re:"Accumulators are not thread-safe by design.".

I did not find this in Spark documentation. You might be referring to Java accumulators I believe. Thread safety of the accumulator in your driver application would depend on the fact how you have implemented the driver program.

However one thing to note that is Accumulators may not be reliable. The unreliability comes from the fact that a failed Spark task  could be retried. In such cases the accumulators will not give you accurate values.

> Re:"Moreover, is .value() operation expensive since it forces all the
>   worker threads to respond and send back values to main driver
>   program?"

I am not sure if that is the case as regardless you use accumulators or no, Executors need to send heartbeat messages back to the driver. Moreover it may not be a lot of data when compared to action such as collect. (If you are working with Big Data). IMO, invoking .value() should not be a big performance concern. Additionally in Batch processing, the driver application you would generally want to invoke .value() once your executors have finished their tasks